# A sample gwt project using requestFactory, activites and places

Tags: gwt

Links to any sample gwt project using requestFactory, activites and places?

Thank you.

Comment: I was trying to get-on with roo + gwt - any links there would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this post](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/using-gwt-requestfactory-with-objectify/) from David Chandler very helpful. It discusses a sample project (source code [here](http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/source/browse/)) using `Request Factory`, `Objectify` and `Activities and Places`.

The project is also discussed in this [Google I/O talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/highly-productive-gwt-rapid-development-with-app-engine-objectify-requestfactory-and-gwt-platform.html). The difference from the original project is that in the talk they use [GWTP](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/) for the MVP part. You should check out `GWTP` also as it really simplifies developing with MVP.

My experience with the roo plugin for GWT and [GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/) wasn't very good. It wasn't very mature when I looked at it (around March 2011), but maybe things have changed since then. For example you had to compile from trunk, as the latest stable version had some bugs, and even then a many to many relation between entities wasn't supported. Documentation was kind of scarce also.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on Roo now, looks very promising in few aspects, will write a blog once I'm successful. once again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The MobileWebApp sample from the GWT SDK ?

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0/samples/mobilewebapp/

Comment: MobileWebApp is for all of desktop browsers, tablets and phones.